# Get Count of Spot Instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

we can use get_cost_and_usage to know the cost spent of spot instance for a particular period of time.

```
            data = self.ce_client.get_cost_and_usage(
                TimePeriod={'Start': start, 'End': end},
                Granularity='DAILY',
                Metrics=['UnblendedCost'], # Valid values are AmortizedCost, BlendedCost, NetAmortizedCost, NetUnblendedCost, NormalizedUsageAmount, UnblendedCost, and UsageQuantity.
                Filter={
                    'Dimensions': {
                        'Key': 'PURCHASE_TYPE',
                        'Values': [
                            'Spot Instances',
                            'On Demand Instances'
                        ],
                        'MatchOptions': [
                            'EQUALS',
                        ]
                    },
                    'Dimensions': {
                        'Key': 'REGION',
                        'Values': args.region,
                        'MatchOptions': [
                            'EQUALS',
                        ]
                    }
                },
                GroupBy=[
                    {
                        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                        'Key': 'PURCHASE_TYPE'
                    },
                ],
                **kwargs
            )
```

I need to get the count of instance that were spot instance for a particular period of time. for example I need the count of spot instances last month.

Comment: Billing only tracks hours. You're best bet for figuring that out might be to query cloudtrail.

Comment: @jordanm is there any way to do this directly via was cli  or boto3.

Comment: @jordanm I need this to automatically get the number of spot instances created last month so that I can do further analysis

Comment: @jordanm how can I use cloudtrail for my requirement?

Comment: You can query ec2 to see all current running spots, then use athena to query cloudtrail to find all terminate ec2 events on spot instances within the last month. The two values combined should be a fairly accurate count of how many existed in the last month.